# Async-await in dart runs synchronously?

Tags: dart, async-await

I am trying out the Future with async await for asynchronous programming.
The code i tested is a simple Future.

```
//order a new coffee perhaps!
Future<String> order(String newOrder){
  final String Function() func = ()=> "${newOrder} is requested!";

  final _order = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5),func);

  return _order;
}
```

When i run this code like  a promise.

```
  order("promised order")
  .then((result) => print(result))
  .catchError((err){
    print(err.error);
  });
```

This behaves like a asynchronous non-blocking code

However the same code when i run it with async/await behaves like  a synchronous code and blocks all the other code, it waits 5 secs to run the next line.

```
void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final _myOrder  = await order('Lattee mocha');
  print(_myOrder);
 //...all the other code waits for
}
```

So i thought async/await is same as futures, where non-blocking..
How come it blocks the other code execution ?

Comment: `await` isn't blocking. What code is waiting 5 seconds to execute? In the promise example when does `print(result)` run? In the `await` example everything after `await` is part of the continuation and will run *after* `await` completes

Answer (score 1):

The *whole point* of the `async`/`await` pattern is to **wait** (hence `await`) until the Future completes and only then continue with this code execution.

Think of it as a way to not have endless `.then()` chains and much simplified error handling.

If you want to *not* wait, then you just leave out the `await` keyword. Obviously, if you don't (a)wait, you don't get the result.

You can still use classic `.then()` chains when it suits your purpose better in your program.

What people talk about when they say "non blocking" they mean that when the compiler sees the `await` keyword, it knows to keep the rest of the program, the event loops, animations etc running and not block *the complete program*.

Comment: Thats true.
I understand what you mean, makes it easy of reading as well.

Comment: But in the point of .then()
it behaves differently,
as on the web it states that it is the same thing as promises.
Future behaves asynchronously non-blocking

Comment: Assuming you mean Javascript promises, Dart Futures behave exactly the same. If you wrote your code for Javascript Promises using async/await, you would get the same output.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: The reason i got confused is when i run the code 
the one with the promise allowed the execution and all the code run and the result of the promise was at the end:
However in the async one the code paused and waited for this to finish and then allowed the execution afterwards hence blocking code

Comment: if you have  a very long process and you use await then all the code will wait for this to finish and causing a delay.
Its not feasible as far as i see

Comment: Well, again, the *whole point* of the "await" keyword is to *wait* and only continue when the Future (or Promise in JS) is done. If you don't want that... *don't use it.* You are free to use the other options like "then".

Comment: Thanks for all your help mate.
I appreciate it:)
for your time and comments.
have  a nice  day

Comment: i try to mark yours as answer and give you points but i could not find it in here.
I am new in here,

Comment: As far as accepted goes, there should be a check mark next to the voting arrows. You can click it if my answer solved your problem.

Comment: İ dont see any voting  i think i am new perhaps thats why do not see it.
i will have  a look at it more,
hope you have  a nice day ahead